# Trim certain lines of .txt file using batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm performing a batch task on my NAS across a large number of media files to ensure they are consistent, but removing the chapter names has got me scratching my head a bit.

I've done a bit of searching and there doesn't appear to be a specific tool for this task, so I've had to improvise. I'm currently able to demux the chapters into the OGG/Text format and then later remux them back in to the source file. This (and the rest of the NAS task) is carried out using windows batch, which means the text file can safely be manipulated between these two processes.

The text file follows the following convention:

```
CHAPTER01=00:00:00.000
CHAPTER01NAME=This is an example
CHAPTER02=00:01:33.333
CHAPTER02NAME=Another_example_here
CHAPTER03=00:02:66.666
CHAPTER03NAME=EXAMPLE 3
```

I'd like to remove any text after CHAPTER##NAME=, resulting in:

```
CHAPTER01=00:00:00.000
CHAPTER01NAME=
CHAPTER02=00:01:33.333
CHAPTER02NAME=
CHAPTER03=00:02:66.666
CHAPTER03NAME=
```

As far as consistency goes, the number of chapters will vary but the format should remain identical. The lines should always alternate between timestamp and name, and the lines requiring the trim should always be the same character length and follow the same formatting.

Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: Step by step hint: `for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%g in ("inputfile.txt") do (echo %%g)` would read a file line by line. Then, instead `echo %%g` try `for /F "tokens=2 delims=0123456789=" %%G in ("%%g") do (echo %%G)`.  Now, instead of `echo %%G`, try `if /I "%%G"=="NAME" (echo need to trim %%g) else (echo %%g)`. Now, instead of `echo need to trim %%g`, try `for /F "delims==" %%x in ("%%g") do (echo %%x=)`. Finally, redirect the output to a `"outputfile.txt"`. **Resources**: https://ss64.com/nt/for.html and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html. HTH.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).